# How to set permalink of your blog post according to date and title of post?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mysql

I am having this website http://www.finalyearondesk.com . My blogs post link are set like this.. http://www.finalyearondesk.com/index.php?id=28 . I want it to set like this ... finalyearondesk.com/2011/09/22/how-to-recover-ubuntu-after-it-is-crashed/ .

I am using the following function to get these posts...

```
function get_content($id = '') {

    if($id != ""):
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $sql = "SELECT * from blog WHERE id = '$id'";
        $return = '<p><a href="http://www.finalyearondesk.com/">Go back to Home page</a></p>';
        echo $return;

    else:
        $sql = "select * from blog ORDER BY id DESC";

    endif;

    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) != 0):

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            echo '<h1><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a></h1>';
            echo '<p>' . "By: " . '<font color="orange">' . $row['author'] . '</font>' . ", Posted on: " . $row['date'] . '<p>';
            echo '<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p><br />';
        }

    else:

        echo '<p>We are really very sorry, this page does not exist!</p>';

    endif;
}
```

Any suggestions how to do this? And can we do this by using .htaccess?

Comment: From poking around on your domain, it looks like you're using WordPress. Can you explain why you're using raw SQL queries and data rather than the templating language? You seem to be trying **WAY** too hard here. As for changing your permalinks, that's something you specify in the blog settings, except it won't work right now because of what you're doing above, manually constructing the `href`s right in the template. This either doesn't make sense, or you need to provide a lot more context as to why you're doing things this way.

Comment: You should use `get_permalink()` to create the permalinks, not some made up PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

yes you simply go into the settings on the backend.

go to the permalinks

choose custom structure

insert this code

/%year%/%month%/%day%/%postname%/

here is a guide

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: -1 Look at the code snippets. Changing the permalink settings is going to have absolutely no effect here, until some significant changes are made to the existing templating.

Comment: You also wouldn't need to set a custom permalink as WordPress's common settings display Year Month Day and post name with the Day and name option

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this piece of code `<a href="index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a></h1>';`

You have hard coded the `index.php?id=` string into your template and even if you turn on permalinks when you click a link this loop generates it'll go to the dynamic URL. Not even the default WordPress dynamic post URL.

A basic WordPress loop which displays the title and date of post similar to what you are trying to acheieve is below

```
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); ?>
      the_time('l, F jS, Y');
   endwhile;
endif;
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

WordPress has many build in functions all with many options. Such as sorting by title, date, asc, dsc etc. You can even use WordPress functions outside of WordPress by including a few php files in the header of your file outside WP.